# Continuous deployment of airflow dags

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have the airflow deployed in Kubernetes and it is using the persistent volume method for dag deployment. I am trying to write a script (using GitHub action for CI/CD) for the deployment of my airflow dags which is somewhat like -

> ```
> DAGS=(./*.py)
>
> for dag in ${DAGS[@]}; 
> do
>   kubectl cp "${dag}" --namespace=${NAMESPACE} ${WEB_SERVER_POD_NAME}:/path/to/dags/folder
> done
> ```

I can successfully deploy new dags and even update them.

But the problem is, I am unable to remove old dags (I used for testing purpose) present in the dags folder of airflow.

Is there a way I can do it?

*P.S.* I cannot use the below command as it would delete any running dags -

```
kubectl exec --namespace=${NAMESPACE} ${WEB_SERVER_POD_NAME} -- bash -c "rm -rf /path/to/dags/folder/*"
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this was an option when you originally posted, but for others:

Github Actions lets you create workflows that are manually triggered, and accept input values. https://github.blog/changelog/2020-07-06-github-actions-manual-triggers-with-workflow_dispatch/

The command would be something like:

```
kubectl exec --namespace=${NAMESPACE} ${WEB_SERVER_POD_NAME} -- bash -c "rm /path/to/dags/folder/${USER_INPUT_DAG_FILE_NAME}"
```